# Order by custom named rows

Tags: postgresql

I’d like to sort my postgres results by some fancy ranking function, but for sake of simplicity, let’s say that I’d like to add two custom rows and sort by them.

```
SELECT my_table.*,
  extract(epoch from (age(current_date, '2012-09-12 10:43:40'::date)))/3600 AS age_in_hours
  Fancy_function_counting_distance() AS distance
FROM my_table
ORDER BY distance + age_in_hours;
```

However, it doesn’t work, since I’m getting error: `ERROR:  column "distance" does not exist`.
Is it possible to order my results by that custom named rows?

I’m running postgres 9.1.x

Comment: arent you calling FROM before you finish telling it what to select?

Comment: you’re right, sorry, fixed example query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the SQL standard, aliases in the `SELECT` list are not visible in `ORDER BY`.

You can use column-position specification (eg `ORDER BY 1,2`), but that doesn't accept an expression; you cannot `ORDER BY 1+2`, for example. So you need to use a subquery to generate the result set then sort it in an outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT my_table.*,
    extract(epoch from (age(current_date, '2012-09-12 10:43:40'::date)))/3600 AS age_in_hours
    Fancy_function_counting_distance() AS distance
  FROM my_table
) x
ORDER BY distance + age_in_hours;
```

Comment: hmm… that kinda sucks (regarding to visibility of aliases) – I don’t know if I can do such subquery (I’m running this query via ORM (ActiveRecord) ), and I don’t know if it will work correctly, by thank you for your answer, it’s really helpful!

Comment: @user1105595 Glad to help. BTW, this will work in MySQL, but only because it doesn't comply with the standard. I'm assured there are good reasons why the standard is written this way, but personally I agree with you - it's a horrid usability wart.